# opening file with java application automatically

Tags: java

I want to create my own file format for a particular kind of file. When someone downloads this file I want their system to know it should be opened with my application.

For example when I download a .doc file, my computer asks me whether I want to save the file or open it with Open Office. Similarly, If that .doc file is sitting on my desktop, and I double click it, it automatically opens with the correct application.

I believe this has to do with associating the file extension with the application in the context of the underlying OS.

Can any one point me to some good resources about how to do this in java?

Thanks.

Edit:
Sorry I want to clarify. Is there a way I can have my application associate the file type with itself when it is installed?

Edit:
found this...
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/jdic_assoc/
platform independent solution

Comment: Google for: `Java File Association`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found this... http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/jdic_assoc/ platform independent solution

Answer (score 1):

This source shows how to make a file association in windows:

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0592.html

You will probably have to do it per installer that you make in each OS.